# Conversion to type int is yielding a negative number

Tags: c#, casting

I encountered a bizarre error when setting the position within a FileStream: "Non-negative number required. Parameter name: value".

```
public string this[Int64 index]
{
    get
    {
        Byte n = Convert.ToByte(0);
        Byte[] Buffer = new Byte[255];
        mem.Position = (int)(index * 256); //Error occurs here
        mem.Read(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);
        Buffer = (from b in Buffer where b != n select b).ToArray();
        return System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(Buffer);
    }
    set
    {
        mem.Position = (int)(index * 256);
        value += String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("\0", 255 - value.Length));
        Byte[] Buffer = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(value + "|");
        mem.Write(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);
    }
}
```

As a long, the index has a value of 8,388,608 and as expected (index * 256) = 2,147,483,648, but when I convert it to an int, I get the same number, only negative. (-2,147,483,648). Why does this happen?

The target framework is .NET 4 and the application is built for "Any CPU".

***Background***

In case anybody is wondering about the purpose of this code, it is part of a class I wrote that mimics string arrays, but without storing the values in memory. The MappedStringArray class allows me to work with files of virtually any size without hitting the limit on RAM because it only knows the position of the rows within a file and reads them out as needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an integer overflow. The value of 2,147,483,648 cannot be represented by an `int`, whose max. positive value is 2^31-1 = 2,147,483,647. (This is in turn because an `int` is a 4-byte = 32 bit value in C#, and because it is a signed int, the very first bit indicates the sign, leaving 31 bits for the actual number).

You can see that 2,147,483,648 is exactly 1 more than that, and so the `int` will overflow, set the first bit to `1` which indicates a negative sign, with the rest being zeroes, and as such, you will receive the biggest negative number possible for an `int`.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently the position property is a long, so I took out the type conversion because it was not needed. However, it is nice to know for future reference that this happens. I would think that if the maximum size were exceeded, then attempting the type conversion would throw an error. If you ask me, it's a little silly that it turns it into a negative number. I mean, what if I were doing a calculation? That would have really thrown a wrench into it.

Comment: But it is something that *has* to happen on the computer. The "turning to the most negative number" has to do with the fixed format of your data (`int` = `int32` = 1 sign-bit, 31 data bits) and the representation of negative and positive values by the two's compliment. You can read up that at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement#Most_negative_number .

Comment: @JoshuaDannemann You can turn on checked arithmetic in the project properties and that will make it throw an exception on all overflows that don't happen inside an `unchecked` block.

Comment: @Kyle Awesome! Moving forward, I will definitely check that option on all my projects!

Answer (score -2):

because  2,147,483,648 is hex x80000000. Thats a negative number as far as int32 is concerned

Comment: @pm100 Some context would help here, as I'd guess OP is unaware of what `x80000000` signifies, or why `int32` would consider an overflow to be negative. [Maximilian's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33352026/1454048) seems to best answer why overflows work in this manner, and touches on the specifics of OP's original question.

Answer (score -2):

The INT is a signed value.
Use the ULONG in your code instead INT.

```
 mem.Position = (Ulong)(index * 256);
```